# Find out which rows of one 2D numpy array are represented in another 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, dask

I have two arrays :

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9],
     [10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15]]

b = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [13, 14, 15]]
```

And I want to find out which rows of first array are represented in second array

```
desired_output = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I have tried this code :

```
x = a == b[:, None] 
row_sums = da.sum(x, axis=2)
output = np.sum(np.where(row_sums == 6,1,0),axis=0)
```

But it creates a massive 3D array - x - which is shaped (a(rows), b(rows), a (or b) (columns)).

```
x.shape() = [5,3,3]
```

And taking into account that my arrays are large, my computer will take a long time to compute it.
Does someone have ideas how to improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each row separately and then merge results using or. Here is sample code:

```py
np.logical_or.reduce([(a == b[i]).all(axis=1) for i in range(b.shape[0])])
```

Result:

```
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is `O(len(a)) + O(len(b))`, rather than `O(len(a) * len(b))`:

```py
set_b = {tuple(row) for row in b}
[tuple(row) in set_b for row in a]
```

Result:

```
[True, True, False, False, True]
```

This relies on tuples being immutable, so you can use them as members of a `set` (or keys in a `dict`).  The first line is `O(len(b))` and the second line is `O(len(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it together with numpy arrays

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15]])

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [13, 14, 15]])
```

Account for the differences in array shape, summarize along the last axis, then the first.

```
# -- step 1
(a == b[:, None]).all(axis=2)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

# -- step 2
(a == b[:, None]).all(axis=2).any(axis=0)
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])


# -- which ones?
w = (a == b[:, None]).all(axis=2).any(axis=0)
a[w]
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```